# Dynamic Programming Problem to Minimize Cost in Creating a non-decreasing array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic, difference, minimize

I have had this problem to solve for a while and have been unable to think of an efficient way to solve this using dynamic programming.

The algorithm I am creating is given an array of integers, {y_1 ... y_n} and a parameter M, and must return a non-decreasing array of integers {x_1 ... x_n}, where no values are greater than M in either array, or less than 0. This must be done to minimize the sum({X_i - Y_i}^2).

As you can see this is not a straightforward problem that can be solved greedily. The solution must be in O(nM) time.

Comment: Is array y ordered in any way?

Comment: No, y is not necessarily in non-decreasing order. If it is, then nothing must be done. If not, then the changes resulting in the minimum difference between array y and array x are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fill in a table `Cost(i, j)` where `i in {1, ..., n}` and `j in {0, ..., M}`. The interpretation of `Cost(i, j)` is that it's the min cost for the sub-problem `y_1, ..., y_i` with limit `j` where `x_i = j` (some of the `y` values may be greater than `j`, but the problem can still be well defined). We have a recurrence for all `i in {2, ..., n}` and all `j in {0, ..., M}`,

```
                      2
Cost(1, j) = |j - y_i|
                                             2
Cost(i, j) =   min   Cost(i-1, k) + |j - y_i|
             0<=k<=j
```

Naively, this is a factor of `M` too slow. If we evaluate `Cost` in the right order, however, we can replace the min with the min of the previous min and `Cost(i-1, j)` and get the desired running time of `O(n M)`.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I was looking for. I believe that I was having trouble visualizing how to calculate the min value without iterating over k, which caused the time complexity of the solution I had, which was O(nMM).